# Books for Geometry processing

Tags: computer-science, 3d, computational-geometry

Please suggest some basic books on geometry processing.

I want to learn this subject for learning algorithms in 3d mesh generation and graphics.

Please suggest me subjects or areas of mathematics i have learn in order to be understanding 3d mesh generation. I am doing self study and i am very new to this topic

Please suggest me online links to any videos or resources, if available.

Comment: Do you need more information about geometry processing?

Comment: yes, i want more information about geometry processing @flashdesign2550 .thank you

Answer (score 4):

See these books:

- [Polygon Mesh Processing](http://www.pmp-book.org) by Botsch et al.
- [Geometry and Topology for Mesh Generation](http://ebooks.cambridge.org/ebook.jsf?bid=CBO9780511530067) by Edelsbrunner

and these courses:

- [Mesh Generation and Geometry Processing in Graphics, Engineering, and Modeling](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/mesh/)
- [Geometry Processing Algorithms](http://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-10-fall/)

Answer (score 1):

I hope these links helpful for you. ;)

> Book

[Dynamic Geometry Processing](http://www.mpi-inf.mpg.de/resources/deformableShapeMatching/EG2012_Tutorial/slides/2.1%20Dynamic_Registration_%28NM%29.pdf)

> Software

[Introduction Software](http://www.mi.fu-berlin.de/en/math/groups/ag-geom/software/index.html)

> Videos

[some Videos](http://www.cgal.org/videos.html)